# How to remove specific word from a field in Elasticsearch Document with Painless Script

Tags: elasticsearch

Imagine that in my documents, I have fields with value like below;

```
field_sample = "marko (budapest)"
```

I want to remove (budapest) from this field, so expected result should be;

```
field_sample = "marko"
```

How can i do this with painless script ?

Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it simply with the following painless script:

```
POST index/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "_id": "doc_id_123"
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.field_sample = ctx._source.field_sample.substring(0, ctx._source.field_sample.indexOf('('))"
  }
}
```